# How to listen the runscope test result?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, integration-testing, runscope

we are triggering the runscope test using triggerid of the specific test. How can we learn the status of the test so we can progress our builds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a [blog post](https://blog.runscope.com/posts/continuous-integration-with-runscope-api-tests-and-codeship-tutorial) that describes how to do this with Codeship, but the same methods (especially the polling done in the [Python sample script](https://github.com/Runscope/python-trigger-sample)) should be applicable to any CI environment.

Comment: Awesome if we can complete this would share a vsts implementation. Any vsts samples ?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for bumping an old post, but I was looking for something similar, that is, checking the Runscope results to automatically approve the next step in a release (as opposed to a build that OP asked about).

It seems that VSTS has the concept of Gates that can do some action and only progress the release when the action succeeds, with configurable timeout and retry. One of the actions is `Invoke REST API`, which would probably do the job.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/approvals/gates?view=vsts

Note, I haven't actually tried this yet, so YMMV